# How can I find the maximal interval of existance for following equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I find the maximal interval of existence for the solution of $\dfrac{dx}{dt}=4x^2$ , $x(0)=5$ including $t=0$ .

Answer (score 2):

Start by finding the solution.  Then see where it is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**. As Robert Israel said, find the solution first. I suggest you rewrite your equation as dt/dx = .... and the problem becomes much simpler; the solution is ..... I am sure you can continue from here.

Answer (score 0):

Separate variables by rearranging terms and then integrating; examine the domain, the set of reals on which the function is defined, and assign the longest interval on which the function is defined to the maximal interval for existence for solutions.